# separating a list into two separate list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

This is my list

```py
lis = [['For the first', '$7.56'], ['For the next', '$16.69'],
['For the first', '$18.34'], ['For the next', '$43.47']]
```

In this there will always be 2 `"for the first"` and N times `"for the next"`
for example;-

```py
lis = [['For the first', '$7.56'], ['For the next', '$16.69'],['for the next','$3.4'],['for the next','$2'],['For the first', '$18.34'], ['For the next', '$43.47'],[for the next,'$34']
```

I want to separate list into 2.

1:from 1st "for the first" to 2nd 'for the first'(not included)
2: from 2nd 'for the first'(included) to last element

```py
delivery=[]
supply=[]

for j in range(1,len(lis)):
    
    if(lis[j][0].lower()=='for the first'):
        
        break
    else:
         delivery.append(lis[j][1])

print(delivery)
```

Comment: Please update your question with a description of what is going wrong.

Comment: show excpected output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can be guaranteed that there will be two items in the list with `'for the first'` in index 0, would do it like this:

```
lst = [['For the first', '$7.56'], ['For the next', '$16.69'],
['For the first', '$18.34'], ['For the next', '$43.47']]

lst_first = []
for i, item in enumerate(lst):
    if item[0].lower() == 'for the first':
        next_occurence = next(j for j, item in enumerate(lst[i+1:], 1) if item[0].lower()=='for the first')
        lst_first = lst[i+1:next_occurence]
        lst_other = lst[next_occurence:]
        break
```

which produces:

```
print(lst_first)  # [['For the next', '$16.69']]
print(lst_other)  # [['For the first', '$18.34'], ['For the next', '$43.47']]
```

---

**Explanation**

The way this works is that it uses a simple `for` loop as in your code to find the first instance of `'for the first'` and then `next` to find the second one. The second search with `next` does not search the entire list but rather the slice of it starting from the element after the first instance. When the two instances are found, the resulting lists are assembled as slices of the first one. After that, we `break` out of the `for` loop.

P.S

whether you need the `lower()` calls or not I will leave up to you. Just note that it is redundant if your input is always consistent.

Comment: thankyou it worked can you please explain what u did

Comment: I updated the answer with a bit of an explanation as to how it words. Judging by your code, you should be able to get it now. I would however recommend to do a bit of reading on how to loop over lists in Python (you do not have to go with the indexes as you do) and how `next` works.

Comment: also in the 1st_first list is there any way that perm_list[0] can be appended too

Comment: there is a way to do everything. You just have to be specific about what it is that you want. I am not sure what `perm_list` is, but you can try playing with the slicing e.g., (`lst_first = lst[i:next_occurence]`, instead of `lst_first = lst[i+1:next_occurence]`). Removing the `+1` will make it inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the amount of times you see `"For the first"`, and depending on that save the values in either first or second list:

```
def split_list(values):
    first_half, second_half = [], []
    first_counter = 0

    for name, amount in values:
        if name == "For the first":
            first_counter += 1
        if first_counter == 1:
            first_half.append([name, amount])
        elif first_counter == 2:
            second_half.append([name, amount])

    return first_half, second_half
```

Using a dict, you can simplify that, the `key` is the amount of times you've seen the pattern, and the value is just the value from the list.

From that you return the ones after first seen, and ones after second seen

```
def split_list(values):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    first_counter = 0
    for name, amount in values:
        if name == "For the first":
            first_counter += 1
        result[first_counter].append([name, amount])
    return result.get(1, []), result.get(2, [])
```

#### [`Code Demo`](https://repl.it/@azro352/FrighteningTroubledPorts#main.py)

---

If you want the new lists to only contain the dollar amount, replace `.append([name, amount])` by `.append(amount)`

Comment: if I am understanding the OP's requirements correctly, this code does not produce the desired result.

Comment: thankyou soo azro for your time ,i got what i was looking for